# How to refresh variable inside div on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable `$count` inside a `<div class="custom">` and I need it resresh if another div class changes. I wrote such a code

```
  $('.test1').on('change', function(e)) {
    $('.custom').text($(this).text());
}
```

But it doesn't refresh this variable.

Here is div block with $prod_count variable

```php
    function commerce_popup_cart_block_view($delta=''){
    $block = array(); 
    switch($delta) {    
    case 'commerce_popup_cart':
      global $user;
      // Default to an empty cart block message.
      $content = '';  
      // First check to ensure there are products in the shopping cart.
      if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

          // Build the variables array to send to the cart block template.
          $variables = array(
            'order' => $order,
            'contents_view' => commerce_embed_view('commerce_cart_block',       'defaults', array($order->order_id), $_GET['q']),
          );
          $count = commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());           
          $quantity = 0;          
          foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item) {
            if (!$line_item instanceof EntityMetadataWrapper) {
              $line_item = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item',   $line_item);
            }
            $types = array('product');

            if (empty($types) || in_array($line_item->type->value(),  $types)) {
              $quantity = $quantity + $line_item->quantity->value();

            }
          }

          $prod_count = t($quantity);  

          if ($prod_count > 0){                                
            $icon = '<div class="cart-icon"></div><div class="cart_popup_count">'.  $prod_count . '</div>';
            $content = '<div id="cart-popup" style="display:none;">' . theme('commerce_cart_block', $variables) . '<div class="popup-arrow"></div></div>';
            $content = '<div class="wrapper">' . $icon . $content . '</div>';  
          } elseif (variable_get('commerce_popup_cart_show_empty_cart', 0) == 1){
            $content = commerce_popup_cart_block_view_get_empty_cart($variables);
          }
      }elseif (variable_get('commerce_popup_cart_show_empty_cart', 0) == 1){        
            $content = commerce_popup_cart_block_view_get_empty_cart($variables = array());          
      }

      // If the superfish module is not installed then add hoverintent script
      if (!module_exists('superfish')){
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','commerce_popup_cart') . '/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js');  
      }

      return array('subject' => t('Shopping cart'), 'content' => $content);
      break;
  } 
  return $block;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You’ve got a typo: `function(e)) {` instead of `function(e) {`.

Comment: second ) closes on event

Comment: No. That needs to go after the closing `}` of the function declaration.

Comment: yeah I changed it few minutes ago but without success

Comment: Please show us where `$count` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should have declare a global variable, then you want to use a namespace of some kind. Just declare the namespace outside, then you can throw whatever you want it. Example

```
var YOUR_VALUE = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
    YOUR_VALUE.check = "";

    YOUR_VALUE.check = "<?php echo $php_VAR; ?>";";
});

console.log(YOUR_VALUE.check); // "TEST CODE"
```

Comment: the variable I want refresh is php variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function myfunction(val)
    {
        $('.custom').val(val);
    }
    </script>


    <input type="text"  class="test1" id="test1" onkeyup="myfunction(this.value);">
    <input type="text"  class="custom" id="custom">
```

Comment: this code working fine for me .i think you have jquery conflict issue .You just add my code in another file and run

Comment: why did you use input's here? I don't need to add this code in html file, it should be in script.js

Answer (score 0):

try it as :

```
$('.test1').on('change', function(e)) { $('.custom').html($(this).html()); }
```

Comment: you need to get the on change of div value and assign it to another as modified above.

Comment: I need to refresh test1 but not custom as variable that have needed value is inside custom so if changes custom, test1 must change as well

Answer (score 0):

It’s not working because you’ve got a syntax error:

```
$('.test1').on('change', function(e)) {
    $('.custom').text($(this).text());
}
// Output: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'. Expected an opening '{' at the start of a function body.
```

The correct syntax is:

```
$('.test1').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.custom').text($(this).text());
})
```

In addition, the `change` event when the user <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>s out of an input field. If you are looking to run this function when the class of the `<div>` is changed, a better solution would either be to call this function directly when you change the class, or to use `MutationObserver`s.

Comment: @rick1 Please clarify exactly what you’re trying to do here. I’m having trouble understanding it.

Comment: If number of products inside the cart changed I want to change number of products outside the card, like on the picture

Comment: without reload of the page. It is works inside the card, but outside it doesn't

Comment: @rick1 So how could the number of products in the cart change? Do you send AJAX calls, or does the customer add to their cart on the page?